# Streamlit - Code block not showing copy to clipboard icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am building a dashboard using Streamlit. I want to create a text box with a copy to clipboard button similar to the image:

[image]

I've added the following code to my dashboard:

```py
st.code("Lorem Ipsum", language="text")
```

But as result, I get the following:

[image]

How can I add that button on my streamlit app as highlighted bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the displayed text, the "copy" button will appear.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately